# How to assign scatter markers by dataframe column? How to avoid TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series' when creating string array from dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, google-maps-markers, scatter-plot

I'm trying to scatter plot data by year (column of dataframe) and assign marker type by detector used (column of dataframe). The following code generates the error 'TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series''; my understanding is because the string array I am creating for the scatter marker is referencing a mutable dataframe rather than copying its data, but if so, how do I copy rather than reference to get the independent vector scatter needs? What code should I be using instead?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.read_excel("..\data.xlsx")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for Year in range(2019, 2024):
    x = data.Cone[(data.Energy==12) & (data.Year == Year)]
    y = data.CalcOverCom[(data.Energy==12) & (data.Year == Year)]
    strings = data.detector[(data.Energy==12) & (data.Year == Year)]
    strings[strings=='semiflex'] = '.'
    strings[strings=='diamond'] = 'd'
    strings[strings=='NaN'] = '1'
    plt.scatter(x, y, marker=strings, label=Year)
ax.set_xlabel('xlabel')
ax.set_ylabel('ylabel')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
ax.set_title('title')
plt.show()
```

I've tried

1. if-elseif-else block within the loop to create a marker specification
2. creating a separate strings vector to use each iteration of the loop

Even if I create an array with these methods with the correct marker types listed, the code fails to execute because of the mysterious 'unhashable' TypeError.

Comment: `marker` does not accept anything array-like. You need a loop.

Comment: What does the documentation mean by array-like in the following, @BigBen? It says "marker: str, array-like, Path, MarkerStyle, or None" at https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle.html#matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle

Comment: Check the `scatter` docs... I think you have the wrong link.

Comment: With `plt.scatter` you can only give one marker, not an array of markers.  As suggested by BigBen, you can create a loop for each kind of marker. Alternatively, you can use seaborn, e.g. `sns.scatter(data=data[date[Energy]==12], x='Cone', y='CalcOverCom', hue='Year', style='detector', markers=['.','d','1'], style_order=['semiflex', 'diamond','Nan'])`

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it appears matplotlib documentation specifies a single string must be used for the `scatter` function, even though it links to a generalized marker style page that mentions an array-like input.

One can use the seaborn software's `scatterplot` function and fill the empty Excel cells with 'unknown' to use this string as both marker specification and legend label. Seaborn would not allow the "1" marker to be used with the other solid markers, so it was replaced with another solid marker "s":

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

QAdata = pd.read_excel("..\Excel-file-in-parent-directory.xlsx")
sns.scatterplot(data=QAdata[QAdata.Energy==12], x='Cone', y='CalcOverCom', hue='Year',
                style='detector', markers=['.','d','s'],
                style_order=['semiflex', 'diamond','unknown'])
plt.xlabel('xlabel text')
plt.ylabel('ylabel text')
plt.title('title text')
plt.show()
```